# Bot selenium, python. time.sleep(n) error

Tags: python, selenium

Is there anything better than selenium if I need to parse and click on DOM elements?

An open browser is optional (rather not needed).

Are there any better options for this?

BTW

Why does error appear after this `time.sleep(n)`.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 39, in <module>
    print("Buy: " + str(elemGreen.text))
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 76, in text
    return self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_TEXT)['value']
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)
```

My Python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

def loginCheck():
    l = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".not-login")[0]
    if(l.text == "Login or Join Trading"):
        return True
    else:
        return False

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://abcc.com/markets/ethusdt")

if(loginCheck() == False):
     print("Next step")
else:
    print("Waiting for the login")
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: The first question is opinion based and not suitable for SO. If opening browser is not necessary you can use headless browser instead.

Comment: The error is not on `time.sleep(n)`, you are trying to use stale element (hence the `StaleElementReferenceException`). If you want help you will have to post the code and relevant html.

Comment: @Guy I added my python code. Help me, if you can

Comment: The error on the line `print("Buy: " + str(elemGreen.text))` is not present in your code trials.

Answer (score 0):

`expected_conditions.visibility_of_all_elements_located` handles `StaleElementReferenceException`. You can use it to locate the element

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions

def loginCheck():
    elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'not-login')))
    l = elements[0]
    if (l.text == "Login or Join Trading"):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```